Cosmos DB - Can't see third level nested JSON data in ODBC Schema Editor
I'm working on a project where I need to connect to a Cosmos DB using a Linked Server connection in SSMS. As I make the connection, I need to use the ODBC Schema Editor to map the data. Within the Schema Editor I can see the first two levels of data (Site > Vehicle), but I can't get to the third level of nested data within Vehicle. Instead, I see 'Vehicle[]' and I know there's another level of nested data called 'Driver[]' within that.
I'm using Collection Mapping to sample the data in Schema Editor. I'm not sure if Table Delimiters would provide a better option. How should I go about navigating this issue?

I found a workaround/solution to this issue. I've found that you can easily establish a connection to Cosmos DB using Power BI, navigate the data structure, and then extract the results to csv.
Follow the steps in this video to establish the database connection and manipulate the data structure. Then you can do what you want with the data (create a report, right-click and export a table to csv, etc). No programming is required with this approach.

I removed all of your editorial stuff about being difficult, wanting you to be a "customer for life" etc. - this is completely the wrong place for such things. Also, link-only answers (like linking to some video) are not valid answers. Note that you're trying to treat Cosmos DB as a relational database and it's not a relational database. Zero to do with customer lock-in.
